# sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash no longer works in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10

I guess it's intended, but is there any related information about this?

We often configure shell to bash for some reason.

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean? What are the symptoms?

Comment: configure just returns with nothing(previously a GUI to select dash or not)

Comment: I think this means dash package no longer provides the reconfigure script

Answer (score 0):

Debian has deliberately remove this function, search the change logs:

- Stop using debconf to select the default /bin/sh.

https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/dash/0.5.11+git20210903+057cd650a4ed-4

Comment: so what is the right and clean way to make bash the system shell (eg. `/bun/sh`)? I hope I don't have to do hands on symbolic links of executable, manpage and all that is needed....

Comment: I updated the symbolic link `/bin/sh` to point to `/bin/bash`, and my debian system hasn't caught fire yet so there's that. I just hope I won't have to do this at every system upgrade.

Comment: Okay it did catch fire eventually. Gnome gets stuck in a loop, returning to the login screen after I enter my password on boot.