# Configure bash instead dash on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: command-line, bash, dpkg, 22.10, dash-shell

On a brand new Ubuntu 22.10 installation I tried the command

```shell
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

That he did nothing

I learned from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437418/sudo-dpkg-reconfigure-dash-no-longer-works-in-ubuntu-22-10) that this feature has been removed.

So what is the right and clean way to make bash the system shell (eg. `/bin/sh`)? I hope I don't have to do hands on symbolic links of executable, manpage and all that is needed....

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the symlink `/bin/sh`. The point of `/bin/sh` is that it should be POSIX compliant, which Dash is - and it's also faster than Bash. So you don't gain anything by pointing `/bin/sh` to Bash - on the other hand you probably loose speed of execution for POSIX scripts.

Comment: Related: [What is the point of sh being linked to dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash/)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know there are differences between `dash` and `bash` ... Although `dash` scripts should **generally** run without issues in `bash`... (But, not vice versa), it's advised to not change the system's default shell as system scripts are written for the default shell and differences/issues might arise in the future.

It's also good to know and comply with the current version of [FHS(*Filesystem Hierarchy Standard*)](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s04.html), definition of `/bin/sh`:

> `sh`  POSIX compatible command shell
>
> If `/bin/sh` is not the POSIX compatible shell command itself, it must
> be a hard or symbolic link to the real shell command.

**That said** ... `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` when choosing <kbd>no</kbd>, changes these symlinks:

```bash
$ ls -l /bin/sh /bin/sh.distrib /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 20 16:10 /bin/sh -> dash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 20 15:42 /bin/sh.distrib -> bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 20 16:10 /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz -> dash.1.gz
```

to these symlinks:

```bash
$ ls -l /bin/sh /bin/sh.distrib /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 20 16:10 /bin/sh -> bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 20 16:10 /bin/sh.distrib -> dash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 20 16:10 /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz -> bash.1.gz
```

and vice versa when choosing <kbd>yes</kbd>.

**That said again** ... Although merely creating symlinks will have the same system shell and `man sh` behavior results, it's worth noting that `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` does that as well with [`dpkg` diversions](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html) ... Hence the existence of `sh.distrib` ... This will have the added effect of `dpkg` recognizing the change and handling those files accordingly:

> File  diversions are a way of forcing dpkg(1) not to install a file
> into its location, but    to a diverted location. Diversions can be
> used through the Debian package scripts to  move    a  file  away when
> it causes a conflict. System administrators can also use it to
> override    some package's configuration  file,  or  whenever  some
> files  (which  aren't  marked  as    'conffiles')  need  to  be
> preserved by dpkg, when installing a newer version of a package
> which contains those files.

The diversion when choosing <kbd>no</kbd> happens as follows:

```bash
Removing 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by dash'
Adding 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by bash'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by bash'
```

That is done like so:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package dash --remove /bin/sh
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package bash --divert /bin/sh.distrib --add /bin/sh
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package dash --remove /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package bash --divert /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz --add /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
```

and when choosing <kbd>yes</kbd> happens as follows:

```bash
Removing 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by dash'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
```

That is done like so:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package bash --remove /bin/sh
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package dash --divert /bin/sh.distrib --add /bin/sh
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package bash --remove /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package dash --divert /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz --add /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz
```

So, if you do the symlinks and then the diversions accordingly, you should get the same end result of running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`.